# PHP looping array into a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a straight forward array with 8 values. I would like to turn it into an multidimensional array. Currently it looks like so:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  float(100)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  float(0.5)
  [5]=>
  float(53.6)
  [6]=>
  float(32.8)
  [7]=>
  float(9.4)
}
```

Using the values above I would like the array to format like so:

```
array[0][0] = 0
array[0][1] = 100

array[1][0] = 0
array[1][1] = 0

array[2][0] = .5
array[2][1] = 53.6
```

etc.

So the goal is to create a loop that loops through and sets every 2 values to an array within an array. Any ideas?

Comment: have you ever used modulus(%) $x%2=???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should break out into the format you described.

```
$newArray = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($originalArray);$i+=2) {
   $newArray[] = array($originalArray[$i], $originalArray[$i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Up voted the array_chunk answer. It is likely more performance friendly and at the very least, easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 7):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split the array every 2 elements.

This piece of code should give you exactly what you are looking for.

```
$newArray=array_chunk($oldArray,2,false);
```

Comment: This was the way I finally have chosen as its less code and works very easily!

Answer (score 2):

```
$output = array();
for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $n = count($array); $i < $n; $i++) {
  $output[$j][] = $array[$i];
  if ($i % 2 == 1) {
    $j++;
  }
}
```

Or...

```
$output = array();
while ($array) {
  $output[] = array(array_shift($array), array_shift($array));
}
```

...and any number of variations on that theme.

Answer (score 1):

Array transformation:

```php
$a = array(0, 100, 0, 0, 0.5, 53.6, 32.8, 9.4);
$b = array();
$j=0;
foreach ($a as $i => $value) {
    if ($i%2) {
        $b[$j][1] = $value;
        $j++;
    } else {
        $b[$j][0] = $value;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_export($a);
var_export($b);
echo '</pre>';
```